# List all directories, sub-directories and count all images within them separately

Tags: php, directory

My folder structure only contains directories, sub-directories and images as either `.JPG` or `.PNG`. I need to list all directories starting from the folder `SOTT_photos/` and count images found in each sub-directory. I've added an example below:

This is what the directory looks like:

```
SOTT_photos 
    Plymouth
       2016
         010416
           berk
             img1.jpg
             img2.jpg
             img3.jpg
           cras
             img1.jpg
             img2.jpg
           jest
             img1.jpg

          020414
            stan
              img1.jpg
              img2.jpg
            bech 
              img1.jpg
```

What I require it to show as:

```
SOTT_photos 
    Plymouth
       2016
         010416
           berk
             3
           cras
             2
           jest
             1

          020414
            stan
              2
            bech 
              1
```

Here is the VERY BASIC, UNFINISHED code I am using, where I have run in to a problem with the counting images.

```
function listFolderFiles($dir)
{
    echo '<ol>';
    foreach (new DirectoryIterator($dir) as $fileInfo) {
        $image_count = 0;
        if (!$fileInfo->isDot()) {
            $file_path = $fileInfo->getPath();
            $file_name = $fileInfo->getFilename();


            if (substr($file_name, -4) == '.JPG' || substr($file_name, -4) == '.jpg') {
                $image_count++;
            } else {
            echo '<li>';
            echo $file_path.' | '.$file_name.'<br>';


            if ($fileInfo->isDir()) {
                listFolderFiles($fileInfo->getPathname());
            }


            echo '</li>';
            }


        }
        echo '<li>'.$image_count.'</li>';
    }
    echo '</ol>';
}
listFolderFiles('../SOTT_photos');
```

This is what it is currently displaying:

```
0
../SOTT_photos | Plymouth
0
../SOTT_photos/Plymouth | even
0
0
../SOTT_photos/Plymouth/even | 060216
0
0
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

Which obviously isn't doing the correct thing. Does anybody have any idea where I may be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to utilise the following perhaps. Edit the path `$dir` to suit your environment - I chose a random directory containing images on my development system to test the code, it seems to work ok.

```
$dir=ROOT.'/images/gallery';

if( realpath( $dir ) ){

    $results=array();

    $dirItr = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $dir );
    $filterItr = new DirFileFilter( $dirItr, array(), $dir, 'all' );
    $recItr = new RecursiveIteratorIterator( $filterItr, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST );


    foreach( $recItr as $filepath => $info ){
        $key = realpath( $info->getPathName() );
        if( $info->isDir() ) {
            $files=glob( $key . '/{*.jpg,.png,*.JPG,*.PNG,*.JPEG,*.jpeg}', GLOB_BRACE );
            $results[ $key ]=count( $files );
        }
    }

    $dirItr = $filterItr = $recItr = null;

    array_filter($results);
    echo '<pre>',print_r($results,true),'</pre>';

}
```

** Edit **
The above does require a class called `DirFileFilter` which I now notice I did not include so do so now:

```
class DirFileFilter extends RecursiveFilterIterator{

    protected $exclude;
    protected $root;
    protected $mode;

    public function __construct( $iterator, $exclude=array(), $root, $mode='all' ){
        parent::__construct( $iterator );
        $this->exclude = $exclude;
        $this->root = $root;
        $this->mode = $mode;
    }

    public function accept(){
        if( !is_readable( $this->root ) ) return false;
        $folpath=rtrim( str_replace( $this->root, '', $this->getPathname() ), '\\' );
        $ext=strtolower( pathinfo( $this->getFilename(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) );

        switch( $this->mode ){
            case 'all': 
                return !( in_array( $this->getFilename(), $this->exclude ) or in_array( $folpath, $this->exclude ) or in_array( $ext, $this->exclude ) );
            case 'files':
                return ( $this->isFile() && ( !in_array( $this->getFilename(), $this->exclude ) or !in_array( $ext, $this->exclude ) ) );
            break;
            case 'dirs':
            case 'folders':
                return ( $this->isDir() && !( in_array( $this->getFilename(), $this->exclude ) ) && !in_array( $folpath, $this->exclude ) );
            break;
            default:
                echo 'config error: ' . $this->mode .' is not recognised';
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }



    public function getChildren(){
        try{
            return new self( $this->getInnerIterator()->getChildren(), $this->exclude, $this->root, $this->mode );
        } catch( Exception $e ){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```